# Polymorphism terminology: "Supertype Reference"?

Tags: oop, polymorphism

This is a question about terminology, not about how things work.

Is there a short term that means: "using an object reference with the datatype of a supertype to refer to an object with the datatype of a subtype"?

Saying "polymorphic reference" doesn't seem to be specific enough because in some languages **ALL** references other than those with the `Object` datatype are polymorphic. I saw one post that referred to these reference variables as a "supertype reference." In the absence of any other (more official) term, I may just use that term because calling a reference a "supertype reference" implies that there is a subtype. It sure beats what I was thinking about using: "sub-as-super." Which, when the inevitable mispronunciations occur, would lead to all kinds of off-color jokes.

What do you all think? Is there an "official" term that all of the dozens of programming books I have read seem to have missed? Or does everyone stumble along, spelling things out with a nearly sentence-long phrase?

Comment: You answered your own question in the title.

Comment: @Kevin, I have never seen that term declared as the "official" or even default standard term to use. I just saw it used in only one post on The Java Ranch. But it seems to fit.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standards body policing the terminology of programming languages.  So looking for an "official" term for anything is likely futile.

Answer (score 0):

There is a principle in object oriented called [DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (Dependency inversion principle).

It's final goal is to reduce coupling by referring object through a abstract supertype.

Many of GoF patterns tries to apply DIP in your code by implementing a abstract supertype and expose this interface for working with subtype.

Comment: While I appreciate the additional information, this does not answer my question about terminology.

Comment: @GrantRobertson DIP exactly use what you explain: _using an object reference with the datatype of a supertype to refer to an object with the datatype of a subtype_